# Better way for Bulk Assignment of Field Level Security

Tags: custom-field, permissions, fields, fls, bulk-permission

In Salesforce we have a custom object which has 500 fields. We have around 50 different profiles in our org. Out of this 50 profiles, 30 profiles need access to these fields.

Right now, to set field level security, we need to open these 500 fields and select all the profiles for which FLS is needed.

Is there any App Exchange tool available which allows these actions to do in bulk? In bulk means, a user can select all the profiles first and in second step user can select all the fields, for which FLS will be assigned.

Please let me know, if anyone is aware of such tools or better way to assign FLS for large number of fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know of any tools that do this, but I'd do one of the following:

1. Update a single profile via the UI to match the appropriate FLS, and then update the other profiles within the force.com IDE.
   i.e. copy and paste the XML from one profile on to the others.  Be careful that you don't override any other values you care about.
   You'd probably want to do a git diff (or similar) to double check you're only updating the appropriate parts of the code
2. Create a permission set for these fields, then apply the permission set to the appropriate users.  If there are a large number of users, you can use an appexchnage product like 'The Permissioner' to assist.

If the number of profiles was smaller, I'd probably use one of the firefox extensions that lets you select an area of checkboxes to tick the correct permissions in the UI.

Answer (score 3):

I have just released recently [a package called BofPerMan](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FtWcBUAV) which gives a flexibility to bulk update Object and Field Level permission

I have shot [a promo video describing capabilities of my package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKkrckTSbxM) BofPerMan which is published on AppExchange.

Here I discuss a possible case of a content management application consisting of two custom objects Book and Movie and a task to set Modify All and Create permission to both of these objects to two custom profiles, Content Manager User and Media Administrator and to Content Manager custom permission set. While this might be nasty and complicated task to perform using standard UI, it can be achieved in few clicks using BofPerMan package! Watch and see this in action

Comment: I've tried this package because of this post, and it works well. I had a few fields that I needed to manually grant permission to in a profile, but it managed the bulk of them without issue. I noticed that it does not list the `Knowledge__kav` object for some reason, so I also had to grant field permissions in this manually.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this [tool](https://profilepowertools.com/#apps/field-level-security) that simplifies the Field Level Security for bulk fields. It also has options to Update Apex Class access as well.